# How can I get desired number of records which matches own filter conditions from AWS Lambda ListFunctions API?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I trying get AWS Lambda functions using `listFunctions` from AWS-SDK of NodeJS.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#listFunctions-property

What I want to do is get desired number of functions which matches own filter conditions; e.g. a functionName is containing string "dev".
This API has `MaxItems`, but we cannot set filter conditions.

So I made a strategy to achieve this.
Set `MaxItems` parameter equals to remaining records.
When I have to get 50 filtered records, set `MaxItems` to 50.

But I think this strategy is inefficient.
It's obvious that I have to call the API repeatedly more often than I need when number of remaining records is 1 or other small numbers.

How can I decide `MaxItems` parameter mathematically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will give you my answer in python, as I dont know node.js.

The best thing is that you do this in 2 steps:

1. First, retrieve all the functions, `setting MaxItems` to a big number.
2. Manually loop through the function names and take as many as you want, matching your criteria.
3. Once your desired number is reached, stop the loop and use the `matched functions` as output.

```py
import boto3

lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda')

# pass the NextMarker only if needed!
func_kwargs = dict(MaxItems=1000)
functions_names_returned = list() # this what you want to return
while True:
    response = lambda_client.list_functions(**func_kwargs)
    functions_info = response['Functions']
    all_functions_names = [x['FunctionName'] for x in functions_info]
    functions_names_returned.extend(all_functions_names)
    marker = response.get('NextMarker')
    if not marker:
        break
    func_kwargs['Marker'] = marker

""" 
now you have retrieved all the functions in a list, 
so you can apply any filtering tecnique to retrieve your wanted
functions. I use a for loop for clarity.
"""
print(f'{functions_names_returned=}')
desired_number_of_functions_to_return = 2
count_returned_functions = 0
all_functions_names_list = list() # this what you want to return
for function_name in functions_names_returned:

    if 'dev' in function_name:
        all_functions_names_list.append(function_name)
        count_returned_functions += 1
    if count_returned_functions == desired_number_of_functions_to_return:
        break
        #exit for loop
print(all_functions_names_list)
```

Comment: @uhey22e youcan accept it as an answer if it answers your question

Comment: For some reason this code only returns up to 5 function names for me, even if I define a larger number for desired_number_of_functions_to_return

Comment: @ire you are right, i improved my answer!

Comment: Hey, thanks for the update. I've tried your updated code and found a new issue. First, if I print 'all_function_names' it only returns 22 names. Letting the for loop after run always returns 2 names, no matter what I change desired_number_of_functions_to_return to. Does it work for you?

Comment: You should print `functions_names_returned` to see all your function names, then if there you have all your functions, you can adjust the `if 'dev' ..` part. I adjusted it again to print all_function_names, there was also a typo.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much.